# TO_NUMBER ignores comma even when it's not in format model

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, string-conversion

I just noticed this and it makes no sense to me:

```
select to_number( '10000', '999G990' ) from dual;

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

OK, that makes sense, the format model contained `G`, the group separator, which didn't match my string and so ORA-01722 was raised.

```
select to_number( '10,000', '999990' ) as x from dual;

         X
----------
     10000
```

But in this case, my format model does *not* contain the group separator and my string does. So shouldn't ORA-01722 be raised again?

And to make absolutely NO sense,

```
select to_number( '10,0000', '999990' ) as x from dual;

         X
----------
    100000
```

Wait, what? 10,0000 isn't even a valid number. Does TO_NUMBER just ignore group separators when they're not in the format model? I can't find anything about this anywhere in the documentation.

Edit:

I've noticed this on Oracle XE (11gR2) and 12cR2. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/122b9d/1) example.

Comment: Your last example is [failing for me](http://rextester.com/PNZWJ96248).  Maybe tell us which version of Oracle you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of those "features" in Oracle that I'm not necessarily a huge fan of.  When attempting a conversion, we will try to "help" by seeing if a conversion is possible if we're confident that there is not ambiguity in the conversion, eg

```
SQL> select to_number( '10,000', '999990' ) as x from dual;

         X
----------
     10000

SQL> select to_number( '10,00000,0', '9999999990' ) as x from dual;

         X
----------
  10000000
```

There are similar behaviours for dates, eg

```
SQL> select to_date('01-MAR-2000','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

TO_DATE('01
-----------
01-MAR-2000
```

So even though the string did not match the format mask, the database performed the conversion anyway due to confidence in the input format.

Comment: I should point out the Number Field in Application Express does not follow this convention. If you enter "10,000" into such a field, you get an "Item must be Numeric" error. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=62159:8